# Load excel files based on file date selection

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have an SSIS requirement:

I have three Excel files with different dates in their file names, stored in a folder.

Folder path: `D:\SourceFolder\`

File names: `Asia_Sale_07May2018.xlsx`, `Asia_Sale_20Jun2018.xlsx`, `Asia_Sale_15Aug2018.xlsx`

I have a package parameter date of `07/15/2018`.

Requirement: Process files where the file name date = parameter date.

If I set parameter date to `07/15/2018` the package should pick & load `Asia_Sale_15Aug2018.xlsx`

If I set parameter date to `06/20/2018` the package should pick & load `Asia_Sale_20Jun2018.xlsx`

If I set parameter date to `05/07/2018` the package should pick & load `Asia_Sale_07May2018.xlsx`

Thanks,
Ayman

Answer (score 1):

1.Loop through the files using ForEach Loop and get the FileName and use Substring to get only the Date Part(07May2018/20Jun2018/15Aug2018 in your case). Convert this to the format you want using convert function.

```
select convert(varchar,convert(date,'15Aug2018'),101)
```

2.Use a precedence constraint in the control flow which compares both the values and load the file if it matches.

Comment: This is the correct way. Pull the date from the filename via expression, and use a foreach loop to go through and pull files matching the parameter.

Answer (score -1):

I would build the name of the file you are looking for and use a foreach loop looking for that specific file.

the C# logic for this is:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2018"); //Just set from your parameter

string str_dt  = dt.ToString("ddMMMyyyy");

string fname = "Asia_Sale_" + str_dt + ".xlsx";
```

Once you've got that, use your variable to check your foreach loop for the file.